# Rust to C++ as Static Library on Windows

Tags: rust, static-libraries, static-linking

I want to create a static library in rust and use it later in c/c++.
I already tried a few things and always get:

```
undefined reference to `hello_rust'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my main.cpp:

```cpp
extern "C" void hello_rust();

int main() {
    hello_rust();
    return 0;
}
```

my lib.rs:

```rs
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn hello_rust() {
    println!("Hello from Rust");
}
```

my commands i tried:
(everytime move .lib file into folder with main.cpp)

```
cargo build --release
g++ main.cpp -o main my_lib.lib
```

or

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -L. -lmy_lib(.lib)
```

or with rustc:

```
rustc --create-type staticlib lib.rs
```

I tried cbindgen crate, manually compiling rust using rustc.. evertime same error. (when doing dynamic libraries everything works fine but i need a static library)

Comment: Post your `cargo.toml` as well.  The way rusts generates libraries by default may not be compatible the way you want it to be.